# Solving PDE with given BCs returns error

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following linear Poisson's PDE with a source term and BCs:
u_xx + u_yy = 10sin(8x(y-1)),  where  -1 < x,y < 1 and u =0 on the boundary

so my attempt was:

```
Simplify[DSolve[{U''[x] + U''[y] == 10*Sin[8*x*(y - 1)], U[1] == 0, 
   U[-1] == 0}, U[x, y], {x, y, -1, 1}]]
```

I get error:

```
DSolve::dsvar: -1 cannot be used as a variable.
```

How can I set up my BCs and interval correctly? Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `DSolve` blindly. Check the document of `DSolve`, you will find example solving Poisson's equation.

Comment: is this supposed to be a rectangle? you only said $-1<x, y<1$. What about the other ends? And $U$ is function of two variables, that is why it is a PDE, so you can't just write $U''[x]$.  Lookup the Laplacian function which makes it easier to write this pde. But without knowing exactly what are the BC, hard to help more. Anyway, Mathematica DSolve can't solve this even on a rectangle. Try NDSolve.  Helmholtz in 2D are hard for computers to solve analytically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica only finds a numerical solution. Try

```
u = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[U[x, y], {x, y}] == 10*Sin[8*x*(y - 1)], 
DirichletCondition[U[x, y] == 0, True]},U , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This matches what I get from MATLAB. Thanks!